# Lenovo Carbon X1 with empty battery

Tags: lenovo, battery

When booting Ubuntu on the laptop the battery appears correct (ca 80%). After a couple of minutes that battery jumps to 0; I receive a hibernation warning and the laptop turns off.

I have unplugged all USB and cables and held power for more than a minute and the problem persists. What could be the cause?

```
$ upower -e
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o001
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o002
/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
```

Comment: 100% a hardware problem and not Ubuntu related. The OS does nothing with a battery. What the OS does is only ask the BIOS statistics about the state of the battery.  When on 80 do a `upower –e` and copy/paste it into the question. Or just replace it

Comment: @Rinzwind I added that. I’ve booted the laptop into windows and after 15 minutes this still hasn’t occurred. I understand that this could be due to a multitude of factors, but it’s still suggestive at least